# matchShapes() opencv giving false positives

Tags: java, opencv, keypoint

I am trying to find an object image into a scene image. I am using opencv to detect the keypoints using SURF. I am using matchDescriptors to match the object descriptors with the scene descriptors, however this is resulting always in object found. Can someone please help out why this is happening? The code is a bit messy since I have tried a lot of options I found but the problem persisted.

```
Mat objectImage = Highgui.imread(Object, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Mat sceneImage = Highgui.imread(Scene, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
MatOfKeyPoint objectKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
FeatureDetector featureDetector = FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.SURF);
//System.out.println("Detecting key points...");
featureDetector.detect(objectImage, objectKeyPoints);
MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_object = new MatOfKeyPoint();
keypoints_object = objectKeyPoints;
System.out.println("Object key points : "+keypoints_object.total());

Mat objectDescriptors = new Mat();
DescriptorExtractor descriptorExtractor = DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.SURF);
//System.out.println("Computing descriptors...");
descriptorExtractor.compute(objectImage, objectKeyPoints, objectDescriptors);

// Create the matrix for output image.
Mat outputImage = new Mat(objectImage.rows(), objectImage.cols(), Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Scalar newKeypointColor = new Scalar(255, 0, 0);

//Drawing key points on object image
Features2d.drawKeypoints(objectImage, objectKeyPoints, outputImage, newKeypointColor, 0);

MatOfKeyPoint sceneKeyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
//System.out.println("Detecting key points in background image...");
featureDetector.detect(sceneImage, sceneKeyPoints);

MatOfKeyPoint keypoints_scene = new MatOfKeyPoint();
keypoints_scene = sceneKeyPoints;
System.out.println("Scene Key points : "+keypoints_scene.total());

//System.out.println("Computing descriptors in background image...");
Mat sceneDescriptors = new Mat();
descriptorExtractor.compute(sceneImage, sceneKeyPoints, sceneDescriptors);

//SceneImage output
Mat matchoutput = new Mat(sceneImage.rows() * 2, sceneImage.cols() * 2, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Scalar matchestColor = new Scalar(0, 255, 0);

//  Drawing key points on scene image;
Mat sceneImg = new Mat(sceneImage.rows() * 2, sceneImage.cols() * 2, Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
Scalar sceneColor = new Scalar(0,0, 255);
Features2d.drawKeypoints(sceneImage, sceneKeyPoints, sceneImg, sceneColor, 0);

System.out.println("Matching object and scene images...");

DescriptorMatcher descriptorMatcher = DescriptorMatcher.create(DescriptorMatcher.FLANNBASED);
descriptorMatcher.clear();
MatOfDMatch matches = new MatOfDMatch();
descriptorMatcher.match(objectDescriptors, sceneDescriptors, matches);
List<DMatch> matchesList = matches.toList();
//descriptorMatcher.knnMatch(objectDescriptors, sceneDescriptors, matches,3);

//System.out.println("Calculating good match list...");
Double max_dist = 0.0;
Double min_dist = 100.0;
for(int i = 0; i < objectDescriptors.rows(); i++){
    Double dist = (double) matchesList.get(i).distance;
    if(dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if(dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
}

LinkedList<DMatch> goodMatchesList = new LinkedList<DMatch>();
for(int i = 0; i < objectDescriptors.rows(); i++){
    if(matchesList.get(i).distance < 1.4*min_dist){
        goodMatchesList.addLast(matchesList.get(i));
    }
}
System.out.println("-- "+goodMatchesList.size());
if (goodMatchesList.size() >= 7) {
    System.out.println("Object Found!!!");
}
```

> object Image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/OmY3o.jpg scene
>   Image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/3wIuq.jpg result
>   image:https://i.stack.imgur.com/yZcqW.jpg

Comment: Don't forget to also provide a sample input image(s).

Comment: I edited my post and included the input sample images